# Failure on import pygame.font

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pygame, libpng

`import pygame` works fine for me, but `import pygame.font` fails with the error:

`ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libfreetype.6.dylib requires version 30.0.0 or later, but libpng15.15.dylib provides version 20.0.0`

This is in Python 2.7 (not the system version), Mac OS 10.9.  I installed libpng-1.6.9 on the idea that libfreetype wanted a later version, but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 5):

What happened was libpng wasn’t installed as a dependency for some reason.  So I grabbed the 64 bit Mac OS X binary at http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html.  But the version was 1.5.4, which is old.

To resolve this, I deleted all of the libpng15 files from usr/local/lib then downloaded the source for 1.5.18 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/1.5.18/ and:

`./configure [--prefix=/path]
make check
make install`

to install.

Issue resolved.  I am going to leave this here in case others have the same problem, since I googled the error quite a bit and couldn’t find a solution.