# Update window caption and play Sound with pygame at same time

Tags: python, audio, text, window, pygame

I've been trying to get a word to pop up with a color and audio in a pygame window for a while but I've been getting this error [Failure on import pygame.font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030935/failure-on-import-pygame-font) and I can't figure it out.  (I have OSX) .

I thought the next best thing would be to have the word in the title of the window (caption) while it played the audio and showed the color. My only problem at this point is that it updates the caption AFTER the tone, not during.  How can I change this?

I'd prefer to move to Tkinter but I don't think you can have the computer generate sounds with frequencies.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Dependencies
import pygame,colorsys,time
import numpy as np
from pygame.locals import *

#Primordial
duration = 2.5
window_size = (320,320)#(320, 568)#(1366, 720)
bits = 16
sample_rate = 44100
n_samples = int(round(duration*sample_rate))
qnty = 3
#basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
#Setup
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -bits, 2)
pygame.init()

#setup our np array to handle 16 bit ints, which is what we set our mixer to expect with "bits" up above
buf = np.zeros((n_samples, 2), dtype = np.int16)
max_sample = 2**(bits - 1) - 1

D_value_freq = {
                "Gamma1" : 300,
                "Gamma2" : 350,    
                "Alpha" :  400, 
                "Beta1" : 450,
                "Beta2" : 500,
                "Cappa" : 550,
                "Delta1" : 600,
                "Delta2" : 650,
                "Epsilon1" : 700,
                "Epsilon2" : 750,
                "Feta" : 800
                }

D_value_color = {
                "Gamma1" : (45,0,45),
                "Gamma2" : (70,0,43),
                "Alpha": (100,39,43),
                 "Beta1" : (100,93,22),
                "Beta2" : (60,100,56),
                "Cappa" : (16,100,84),
                "Delta1" : (12,100,91),
                "Delta2" : (34,49,100),
                "Epsilon1" : (2,32,100),
                "Epsilon2" : (27,44,92),
                "Feta" : (34,65,62)
                }       

for i in range(qnty):
    #Choose note
    value = np.random.choice(D_value_color.keys(),size=1)[0]
    color, frequency = D_value_color[value], D_value_freq[value]
    frequency_l = frequency_r = frequency/2.0
    #Color screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
    pygame.display.set_caption(value)
    screen.fill(color)
    pygame.display.update()
    #Sounds
    for s in range(n_samples):
        t = float(s)/sample_rate    # time in seconds
        #grab the x-coordinate of the sine wave at a given time, while constraining the sample to what our mixer is set to with "bits"
        buf[s][0] = int(round(max_sample*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency_l*t)))        # left
        buf[s][1] = int(round(max_sample*0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency_r*t)))    # right


    sound = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(buf)
    #play once, then loop forever

    sound.play(loops = 0)

    time.sleep(duration)
```

Comment: in `for` loop you use `set_mode` so you destroy old window and create new one many times - you don't need it. Use `set_mode` only once. And don't use `;` because it is less readable. Everyone expect one command in line.

Comment: How can you update the name of the window every time you iterate?

Comment: PyGame has [pyame.time.wait](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait) - you don't need `time` module.

Comment: I use `set_caption()` - nothing more.

Comment: do you draw anything on screen ? if not then you don't need `fill()` and `update()`. Or use it only once - before `for` loop` .

Comment: small "workaround" for font problem: you can draw bitmaps with letters :)

Comment: Are you on OSX 10.11? I've heard that pygame doesn't work very well on the newest os.

Comment: Not. I use Linux Mint.

Comment: I'm on Yosemite not El Capitan.  I want the screen to be colored, hence the fill and update mode. Lol, I could do bitmap letter! That's a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not answer for your problems but this code works for me on Linux Mint. It change caption before sound - but it can be problem only on OSX.

```
import pygame
import numpy as np

#
# pygame (simple) template by furas
#

# === constants == (UPPER_CASE names)

# Primordial
DURATION = 2.5
WINDOWS_SIZE = (320,320) #(320, 568)#(1366, 720)
BITS = 16
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100
N_SAMPLES = int(round(DURATION*SAMPLE_RATE))
QNTY = 3

D_VALUE_FREQ = {
    "Gamma1" : 300,
    "Gamma2" : 350,    
    "Alpha" :  400, 
    "Beta1" : 450,
    "Beta2" : 500,
    "Cappa" : 550,
    "Delta1" : 600,
    "Delta2" : 650,
    "Epsilon1" : 700,
    "Epsilon2" : 750,
    "Feta" : 800
}

D_VALUE_COLOR = {
    "Gamma1" : (45,0,45),
    "Gamma2" : (70,0,43),
    "Alpha": (100,39,43),
    "Beta1" : (100,93,22),
    "Beta2" : (60,100,56),
    "Cappa" : (16,100,84),
    "Delta1" : (12,100,91),
    "Delta2" : (34,49,100),
    "Epsilon1" : (2,32,100),
    "Epsilon2" : (27,44,92),
    "Feta" : (34,65,62)
}       

# === classes === (CamelCase names)

  # empty

# === functions === (lower_case names)

  # empty

# === main === (lower_case names)

# --- vars ---

# setup our np array to handle 16 bit ints, which is what we set our mixer to expect with "bits" up above

buf = np.zeros((N_SAMPLES, 2), dtype = np.int16)
max_sample = 2**(BITS - 1) - 1

# --- init ---

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -BITS, 2)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOWS_SIZE, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

# --- other ---

#basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48) # use after `pygame.init`

# --- mainloop ---

running = True

for i in range(QNTY):

    # clear events queue
    # TODO: check events during time.wait to close window faster
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # quit by clicking "X" window button 
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: # quit on ESCAPE key
                running = False

    if not running:
        break

    # Choose note

    value = np.random.choice(D_VALUE_COLOR.keys(), size=1)[0] # WRONG!
    color = D_VALUE_COLOR[value] # one command by line - it is more readable
    frequency = D_VALUE_FREQ[value]
    frequency_l = frequency_r = frequency/2.0

    print(i, value)

    # change caption

    pygame.display.set_caption(value)

    # change color

    screen.fill(color)
    pygame.display.update()

    # sounds

    for s in range(N_SAMPLES):
        t = float(s)/SAMPLE_RATE    # time in seconds
        #grab the x-coordinate of the sine wave at a given time, while constraining the sample to what our mixer is set to with "bits"
        buf[s][0] = int(round(max_sample*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency_l*t)))        # left
        buf[s][1] = int(round(max_sample*0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency_r*t)))    # right

    sound = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(buf)
    #play once, then loop forever

    sound.play(loops=0)

    pygame.time.wait(int(DURATION*1000))

# --- the end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It's still popping up late :/

Comment: it have to be problem only on OSX :/ On Linux it shows (and `print()`) before sound.

Comment: The print pops up at the right time but the caption doesn't. any resources to do bitmap images of text on the screen instead?

Comment: free elements on [OpenGameArt](http://opengameart.org/content/font-art-collection)